# Debug STM32 no Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, microcontrolador

Alguém sabe como *debugar* no Eclipse em tempo real?

Tenho um *firmware* para microcontrolador STM32 e queria ver minhas variáveis mudando com o tempo sem precisar usar *breakpoint* ou coisa do gênero.

Answer (score 0):

STM-STUDIO-STM32 que é uma grande ferramenta fornecida pelo ST para monitoramento de dados em tempo real.

Os dados podem ser exibidos em gráficos de barras, gráficos XY e em tabelas.
As variáveis ​​são carregados a partir do arquivo .elf.
A ferramenta usa ST-Link e o SWD para se conectar a um chip e aquisição de dados.
Você pode até mesmo alterar o valor das variáveis ​​durante o tempo de execução, por isso funciona como uma entrada para o MCU também.

Download: [STM-STUDIO-STM32](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm-studio-stm32.html)